# "chatgpt" is the top tag. Do we want it to be used only on questions about the cross-platform application software from OpenAI?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

Looking at the Tags page, I noticed that as of July 18th, 20:13 UTC-6, [chatgpt](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) is the top tag having six questions.

---

Update: as of July 24, 16:26 UT-6, [chatgpt](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) is still the top tag, having 19 questions.

---

Despite what questions have this tag, I wonder if we want to use it for questions about anything that it's labeled "ChatGPT" or if we want to use this tag only for questions about the application software launched on Nov 30, 2022, by OpenAI that nowadays also is available as for the Web and on the Apple App Store.

I created the tag wiki a few moments ago by entering the tag usage guidance (tag excerpt). This question is not intended to ask for criticism about it but to ask the community about the use of tags.

I'm open to editing the tag excerpt based on participation in this tag. So, what questions should the [chatgpt](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) tag be used, only one of the "original" ChatGPT? On anything labeled "ChatGPT" despite being a hoax? Should it also be used on questions about the OpenAI Chat API?

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be used for anything related to the label `ChatGPT`. It is somewhat broad, yes. It makes sense as it is. We can, however, make more specific tags to be used along with [chatgpt](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt) for more specific topics. For example, [terminology](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), [prompt-design](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-design), or whatever the case may be.

Comment: Although I don't prefer "ChatGPT" being used as a general term, I won't contest against it. P.S. I will wait for a bit before accepting this answer to let others join this conversation.

Comment: Do you consider the Chat Completions API to be ChatGPT, or only chat.openai.com?